# Using in Socket.io in ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: node.js, asp.net-mvc, socket.io

I know how to use socket.io with node.js as back end , would like to know if it can also be used in an ASP.NET MVC application.

If yes , then could you provide more information.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement Socket.IO with ASP.Net, IISNode, Node.JS, and SQL Server for event-based push notifications?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9570522/how-to-implement-socket-io-with-asp-net-iisnode-node-js-and-sql-server-for-ev)